# Do we really need a page to indicate that introduction slides are about to begin?

Tags: gui-design, mobile, design, slideshow

I am designing a mobile app. To make users aware about the app concepts, I am adding few slides (pages with dot indicators at the bottom). These slides will appear when the user opens the app for first time after completing  the installation. These slides will have a SKIP button at the bottom left corner to allow user to skip the introduction part and jump directly to application's main page.

My question is do we need a page which has a button to launch the slides and which tells user that a application introduction slides are about to begin?

[image]

Do we really need a screen like this? Or can we directly show the first page of the introduction slides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **No**.

It's a given that if the user is launching the app for the **first time**, you'll start away with the Introduction.

A good **onboarding** experience exists when it dives right into the introduction of an app.

Always have a Skip button in the Introductory slides so if the user has used the app before, he may skip the intro and dive right into the functionality.

When you give the User an option of if you'd like they would want to **Launch Tour** or **Skip**,
they do not know the experience they're about to get in the tour and think it's a waste of their time, and most of them will tap Skip.

To avoid this, it's ideal to dive right into the tour if it's the first launch and showcasing a skip option in each introductory slide to take them right to the actual app.

Answer (score -1):

There are different kinds of people using an app.

There are those who want to dive and start exploring. I know for one I am from this type of people. I prefer to frustrate myself trying to figure out how something works, rather than see a tutorial or tour.

There are also those who will thoroughly study your tour (if there is one) before getting acquainted with your app.

The key is to find intuitive ways to do it. For example, prompting to skip the tour is good for people like me. Taking the tour on the other hand is something that another type of user will prefer.

So for those then, keeping in mind a few patterns will help:

- Not so much text or info - keep it simple.
- Put the most important aspects - not everything that your app is capable of doing.
- Consider making it fun - add microinteractions (gamifying the tour)
- Add many possible scenarios to your tour and do A/B testing.

Comment: This begs the question though. If you have to provide a "tutorial," is the application user friendly to begin with?

Comment: @Majo0od You have a good point, and the answer totally depends on the complexity. Looking at games, a tutorial can give a good understanding of the whole way of thinking in the game to understand how to achieve things. The same counts for complex applications where it ’s crucial to get the mindset of the user (mental model) in sync with the app to make things more intuitively understood.

Comment: I'm glad you brought up a game, because even in games it's frowned upon to show a tutorial because that's telling the player "this is way too complex for you to ever figure out on your own," which is a bad user experience. A user should be able to discover on their own and understand what the application does from the start, then learn as they go.

Comment: This isn't relevant to the specific question of whether the intro slides should start with an intro intro slide. The OP mentioned that there would be a skip button regardless.